# How to create 10 by 10 grid

Tags: ruby, matrix

I have created this program which currently creates a grid of x rows and y columns, however always displays a 4X4 grid, even if you enter 10 rows 10 columns. How would you create a 10 by 10 grid?

Comment: The code works fine for me. Are you sure you posted the correct code? Could you post a screenshot of what you think is wrong?

Comment: The code reproduces the problem for me, though. It only displays a 4X4 grid, instead of 8X8.

Comment: I have modified the code you gave to display a chess board. Is this how you'd like the board to look? Your solution doesn't stay consistent with the original board, so you might want it to look like the old version, just with black and white tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with the original code is that all of the tiles are being displayed as white. I believe the reason there are black borders in the original example is, because of the how the co-ordinates worked out. Many of the co-ordinates end in `.5`, which are rounded by pygame. So, as a result, your program creates an 8X8 grid, but doesn't display them correctly, and borders are only seen after every 2 tiles.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you found this answer helpful, or it answered your question, remember to [vote and/or accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks!